# Collecting a released rope with a proper speed

Tags: mechanisms, friction, pulleys

To simplify the problem, I liken the problem to a ship approaching the shore and a device wants to collect the rope in such a way that the rope is neither stretched too much nor released to the extent that it falls into the water.

For this purpose, I thought that a motor with a ratchet should collect the rope at a high speed, but if the rope resists too much, the device should not put too much pressure on it. Because our device is not going to pull the ship to the shore! We just want to collect the rope.

The problem is apparently similar to the function of the clutch, but I am looking for a more geometric and mechanical solution because **the main product is a very delicate device** (not really for a ship but in a fine robotic system) and the implementation of the clutch function in these dimensions requires high technology in terms of materials and precision settings.

Comment: mass of rope? does it increase when wet? What have you considered so far so we don't waste time suggesting things you have already considered / rejected?

Comment: The main device is not really for ship and ropes in water. It is a delicate robotic device. we just need to maintain the rope stretched. @SolarMike

Comment: So check out some of the systems used in winches, both hydraulic and electric - especially when rewinding. Also check out cable winding systems used when winding cable rolls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to a low-tension rewinder application used for filaments and films / webs.

The simplest solution would be to run a rewinder motor in constant torque mode. This could be achieved with a DC motor by driving it with constant current.

Other methods would feed the rewinder via a roller on a "dancer" arm. If the dancer arm starts to fall below mid-position the motor speeds up. If it goes above mid-position it would run in reverse (until it reaches mid-position).

The complexity of the control system really depends on how complex the motion of the material is. Steady and smooth feed can be rewound with relative ease.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest method: torque-limiting clutch.  I have one on my electric screwdriver.
Less simple but even finer control: torque sensor with feedback to the motor winding speed.